# Heat equation: Squiggly lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am working on recreating an image of an heat equation as shown below

[image]

I have mostly been successful, however I am still not sure how to add the squiggly lines. Is there also an easier way to make sure the labels `1`,`0`,and `1`, are properly aligned? In the figure they have the same baseline, but in my graph they vary.

Any other improvements or ways to create the displayed image are appreciated as always

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{UiT-main}{HTML}{003349}
\definecolor{UiT-blue}{HTML}{007396}
\definecolor{UiT-red}{HTML}{CB333B}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\xmax{2}\def\ymax{2}
    % Shade the box
    \shade[top color=white,bottom color=UiT-blue] (0,0) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
    % Draw the border of the box and add labels
    \draw [color=UiT-blue] 
               (0,0)         -- (\xmax,0)     node [pos=0.5,label=below:{\color{UiT-red}$u=g$}]{}
               (\xmax,0)     -- (\xmax,\ymax) node [pos=0.5,label=right:{\color{UiT-red}$u=0$}]{}
               (\xmax,\ymax) -- (0,\ymax)     node [pos=0.5,label=above:{\color{UiT-red}$u=0$}]{}  
               (0,\ymax)     -- (0,0)         node [pos=0.5,label= left:{\color{UiT-red}$u=0$}]{};
    % Add the S in the centre
    \path (0,\ymax)         -- (\xmax,0)     node [pos=0.5]{$S$};
    % Draw the axis
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (-1,0) -- (.5+\xmax,0) node[anchor= west] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,.5+\ymax) node[anchor=south east] {$y$};
    % Label the axis
    \node[below left] (0,0) {$0$};
    \node[label=left:{$1$}] (s2) at (0,\ymax) {};
    \node[label=below:{$1$}] (s4) at (\xmax,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can create squiggly lines with something like `\draw (0,0) to[out=90, in=-90] (1,1);`.

Comment: You may use `pin` and redefine pin on way as is described in *17.10.3 The Pin Option* in TikZ & PGFmanula, pp 249 (v 3.1.4b)

Comment: How is the first figure an "image of an heat equation"?

Comment: @rafa11111 It is a very simple model where the temperature is g(x) at the x-axis then it decreases linearly with y until it reaches zero at y = 1. The plate is also insulated so the borders have a temperature of 0. That is the u = 0 ... parts =)

Comment: Of course, but I cannot see how it is relevant to the question, since it is about the squiggly lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very similar to Skillmons answer (in that this uses `in` and `out`).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,bending}

\definecolor{UiT-main}{HTML}{003349}
\definecolor{UiT-blue}{HTML}{007396}
\definecolor{UiT-red}{HTML}{CB333B}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\xmax{2}\def\ymax{2}
    % Shade the box
    \shade[top color=white,bottom color=UiT-blue] (0,0) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
    % Draw the border of the box and add labels
    \draw [color=UiT-blue] 
               (0,0)         -- (\xmax,0)  coordinate[pos=0.6] (p1)   node[pos=0.5,UiT-red,below=1em](u1){$u=g$}
               (\xmax,0)     -- (\xmax,\ymax) coordinate[pos=0.6] (p2)  node[pos=0.5,UiT-red,right=1em](u2){$u=0$}
               (\xmax,\ymax) -- (0,\ymax) coordinate[pos=0.6] (p3)     node[pos=0.5,UiT-red,above=1em](u3){$u=0$}
               (0,\ymax)     -- (0,0) coordinate[pos=0.6] (p4)          node[pos=0.5,UiT-red,left=1em](u4){$u=0$};
    \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
    {\draw[-{Stealth[bend]},UiT-red] (u\X) to[out=\X*90,in=\X*90-180] (p\X);}              
    % Add the S in the centre
    \path (0,\ymax)         -- (\xmax,0)     node [pos=0.5]{$S$};
    % Draw the axis
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (-1,0) -- (.5+\xmax,0) node[anchor= west] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,.5+\ymax) node[anchor=south east] {$y$};
    % Label the axis
    \path (0,0) node[below left]  {$0$}
    (0,\ymax) node[left] {$1$} (\xmax,0) node[below] {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer as always Mormont! Any idea how to align the `0` with the two `1`s in the picture? =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I added something in which they are aligned. The issue is that you were using `label` in situations in which IMHO just nodes are the cleaner option.

Comment: I agree that nodes are cleaner, why did I not think of that. Sorry for still being a novice when it comes to tikz. Thanks again for a wonderful answer

Answer (score 7):

Packing the lines into it with `to` and the `out` and `in` keys (quick and dirty).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{UiT-main}{HTML}{003349}
\definecolor{UiT-blue}{HTML}{007396}
\definecolor{UiT-red}{HTML}{CB333B}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\xmax{2}\def\ymax{2}
    % Shade the box
    \shade[top color=white,bottom color=UiT-blue] (0,0) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
    % Draw the border of the box and add labels
    \draw [color=UiT-blue] 
               (0,0)         -- (\xmax,0)     node
               [pos=0.5,label=below:{\color{UiT-red}$u=g$}](b){}
               (\xmax,0)     -- (\xmax,\ymax) node
               [pos=0.5,label=right:{\color{UiT-red}$u=1$}](r){}
               (\xmax,\ymax) -- (0,\ymax)     node
               [pos=0.5,label=above:{\color{UiT-red}$u=2$}](t){}  
               (0,\ymax)     -- (0,0)         node [pos=0.5,label=
               left:{\color{UiT-red}$u=3$}](l){};
    % Add the S in the centre
    \path (0,\ymax)         -- (\xmax,0)     node [pos=0.5]{$S$};
    % Draw the axis
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (-1,0) -- (.5+\xmax,0) node[anchor= west] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,.5+\ymax) node[anchor=south east] {$y$};
    % Label the axis
    \node[below left] (0,0) {$0$};
    \node[label=left:{$1$}] (s2) at (0,\ymax) {};
    \node[label=below:{$1$}] (s4) at (\xmax,0) {};
    %
    \draw[<-,UiT-red] (b.center)++(.1,-0.01) to[out=-90,in=90] ++(-0.2,-0.25);
    \draw[<-,UiT-red] (r.center)++(.01,+0.1) to[out=0,in=180] ++(0.25,-0.2);
    \draw[<-,UiT-red] (t.center)++(.1,0.01) to[out=90,in=-90] ++(-0.2,0.25);
    \draw[<-,UiT-red] (l.center)++(-.01,+0.1) to[out=180,in=0] ++(-0.25,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]